# Deauthentication through Dropbox JSON API (webhooks)

Tags: dropbox-api

We're using the Dropbox API in our App but haven't found a way to succcessfully deauthenticate.

Currently we call the disable_access_token on logout, which works (i.e. subsequent calls using the token fail).

Unfortunately, the next time the OAuth2 login process is initiated the session gets completely revived without asking the user for their credentials, meaning that until the app is uninstalled, only one Dropbox user can be authenticated.

This seems to be a regression issue as everything was working a few weeks ago (that is, the session was not being revived automatically).

EDIT

To be clear, I'm looking for a way to deauthenticate the user in such a way that when the OAuth process is run again the user is presented with the login page. This is fairly compulsory behaviour, so I'm hoping somebody has found a way.

Comment: What exactly is being asked here?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I have found the solution.

Send a request to:
http://www.dropbox.com/logout?access_token=XXXXX

This will disable the access token and prevent the OAuth process from automatically reviving.

Comment: I don't think that actually does anything relating to that specific access token. It just logs the user out (so they'll be forced to log in the next time they do something, like authorize your app).

Comment: @smarx, do you know if passing an access_token parameter to this URL has any effect, or if it's equivalent to passing no parameters? I'd like to upvote this answer if it's correct, or write a new one otherwise. I think the original asker was looking for this behavior (being forced to log in again), as I was.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior you're objecting to is that the user gets auto-redirected without having to "allow" your app again. This happens if the user has at least one usable access token for your app.

`/disable_access_token` only disables a single access token, so if the user has others, they'll continue to get immediately redirected.

So you can either be careful to always revoke every token for a user (not always possible, e.g. if they don't use the logout functionality in your app), or you'll have to disable auto-redirection altogether. You can do that by setting the `force_reapprove` parameter to `true` when you redirect the user to [`/oauth2/authorize`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize).

Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: I think what the user is talking about is slightly different. What I'm seeing: 1) connect and authorize and get a token, 2) use API, 3) disable token, 4) open embedded browser to log in again, 5) embedded browser logs them in directly and issues a new token without prompting for credentials. So it's not about authorizing the app, it's about getting user credentials. So far I haven't been able to tell how the website is deciding it's the same user (maybe a cookie?). The behavior is different if I close and reopen the app after step 3. Any ideas?

Comment: I think we're talking about the same thing. If the user is still logged in to dropbox.com (yes, users are remembered by cookies), and if they still have at least one valid access token for the app, and you haven't included `force_reapprove=true`, then the user will be automatically redirected without having to click "allow" again. My guess is that restarting your app is clearing the cookies for the embedded web view. The user should still be auto-redirected after they log in, though. (Whether they have to click "allow" or not is based solely on whether they have an access token.)

Comment: I hope I'm not being dense - you mentioned the Allow and force_approve tags, but the thing I'm wondering about is the Dropbox login itself (before the place where we would click Allow). Anyway I think you may be right about cookies and the embedded browser. I'm going to keep playing with it and hopefully will either find what I'm doing wrong or be able to formulate a better question. :) Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If you want to log the user out of dropbox.com, you could clean up the cookies or send the user to dropbox.com/logout.

Comment: I tried the logout link with no success yesterday, but I'm going to try again in case I messed up somehow. Failing that the cookie cleaning was the next thing I was going to try.

Comment: The explicit logout did work, I was just being a bonehead and issuing the request from my REST client rather than from the embedded browser. Doing the latter made it work correctly. Thanks so much!