# Deauthentication of user from Dropbox API

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing a chrome application for storing encrypted user files. It uses Dropbox as a backend cloud storage file system. For simplicity the user logs in to the app using OAuth2 protocol of [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize). Now for logging out the user I used the `/disable_access_token` as mentioned on the API page. This revokes the `access_token` but does not completely logs out the user because the next time I launch the app and click on `login` the app does not prompts for user credentials hence automatically logging in the previous/same user again.

Same question was asked at this link: [Deauthentication through Dropbox JSON API (webhooks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133536/deauthentication-through-dropbox-json-api-webhooks) but I did not get a satisfactory working answer over there and because of low reputation points currently could not even comment there.

EDIT: I tried removing all cookies set from the domains of dropbox.com as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what's missing for you from the question you linked to? The two answers there seem to cover both the API and web aspects of this.

Comment: @Greg consider this scenario: `User A` is initially logged in to the app. Now he logs out which triggers the `disable_access_token` and shows the logout view. Next `User B` wants to use the extension and he clicks on login button. What happens is, instead of prompting the `User B` for login credentials the app directly logs him into `User A` account. the 1st answer using `force_reapprove` is not the solution because the approval window that opens up on clicking login button still has `User A` logged in, though you get a option to logout and sign in as `User B` there.

Comment: @Greg I tried the second answer on that link, that doesn't works either.

Comment: So it sounds like you need to end the user's web session. In that case, you should just send them to https://www.dropbox.com/logout like the first answer mentions. (You shouldn't include the access_token parameter like that example does though.)

Comment: @Greg I already mentioned in my previous comment that redirecting the user to dropbox.com/logout doesn't works either. That doesn't even sounds logical, why should the user be redirected to some link outside the app

Comment: In what does it not work specifically? Users authorize apps via the web site, and if you need the user's web session in their browser to be end sending them to /logout is the way to do it.